# Why I can set! builtin dynamic (?) Clojure vars?

Tags: clojure, dynamic-variables

Why I can do this:

```
> (set! *unchecked-math* true)
true
> (set! *warn-on-reflection* false)
false
```

but can't do this:

```
> (def ^:dynamic *x*)
#'user/*x*
> (set! *x* 1) ;; no luck, exception!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible the builtin dynamics are implicitly wrapped in a binding form by the runtime? Because this works, for example:

```
user=> (def ^:dynamic *x*)
user=> (binding [*x* false] (set! *x* true))
true
user=>
```

One thing to note is that the documentation explicitly says that its an error to try and modify the root binding via `set!`, see:

http://clojure.org/reference/vars

It's also possible that the builtins are treated exceptionally, for example if you look at the metadata of x:

```
user=> (meta #'*x*)
{:dynamic true, :line 1, :column 1, :file "/private/var/folders/8j/ckhdsww161xdwy3cfddjd01d25k_1q/T/form-init5379741350621280680.clj", :name *x*, :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x6b8f00 "user"]}
```

It's marked as dynamic, whereas `*warn-on-reflection*` is not marked as dynamic but still works in a binding form:

```
user=> (meta #'*warn-on-reflection*)
{:added "1.0", :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x377fc927 "clojure.core"], :name *warn-on-reflection*, :doc "When set to true, the compiler will emit warnings when reflection is\n  needed to resolve Java method calls or field accesses.\n\n  Defaults to false."}
user=> (binding [*warn-on-reflection* true] (set! *warn-on-reflection* false))
false
user=>
```

Presumably this is for backward compatibility because in earlier versions of clojure vars with earmuffs (stars in each side) were dynamic by convention. But anyway this just goes to show that builtins are treated slightly differently.

Now, I decided to take this a bit further, and `grep` the source code of clojure, looking for `warn-on-reflection`, which leads me to the constant `WARN_ON_REFLECTION`, which leads me to lines of code like this in `RT.java`:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L467

```
Var.pushThreadBindings(
        RT.mapUniqueKeys(CURRENT_NS, CURRENT_NS.deref(),
               WARN_ON_REFLECTION, WARN_ON_REFLECTION.deref()
                ,RT.UNCHECKED_MATH, RT.UNCHECKED_MATH.deref()));
```

Which leads me to believe that my initial assumption was correct, that certain special global vars are implicitly wrapped in a thread local binding.

EDIT:

As mentioned in a comment, you can use `clojure.core/push-thread-bindings`, but be sure to follow the advice of the documentation and wrap in try/catch/finally with `pop-thread-bindings` in the finally block. And at that point you would have just re-implemented `binding` (e.g. run `(source binding)` at the repl), which is probably why the doc explicitly warns that `push-thread-bindings` is a low level function and `binding` should be preferred.

Comment: Now I see, thanks! Also [that's why](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/d920ada9fab7e9b8342d28d8295a600a814c1d8a/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L228) I couldn't find the definition of `*warn-on-reflection*` in `clojure.core`.

Comment: You might want to add that you can probably make your own dynamic variable act the same with https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/push-thread-bindings.

Answer (score 4):

Perusing the doc, you'll find

```
user=> (doc thread-bound?)
-------------------------
clojure.core/thread-bound?
([& vars])
  Returns true if all of the vars provided 
  as arguments have thread-local bindings.
  Implies that set!'ing the provided vars will succeed.  
  Returns true if no vars are provided.
```

in particular:

> Implies that set!'ing the provided vars will succeed

so, this means you can check if `set!` is possible as follows:

```
user=> (thread-bound? #'*x*)
false
user=> (thread-bound? #'*unchecked-math*)
true
```

which means you can only `set!` thread-bound vars, which your `*x*` is not (yet).

---

PS: in [Kevins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602323/kevin) answer you'll see `Var.pushThreadBindings` which presumely is actually avaliable as `clojure.core/push-thread-bindings` - if you wan't to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [reference on Vars](http://clojure.org/reference/vars), you can only use `set!` assignment on thread-bound vars:

> Currently, it is an error to attempt to set the root binding of a var
>   using set!, i.e. var assignments are thread-local. In all cases the
>   value of expr is returned.

However, the built-in dynamic vars like `*warn-on-reflection*` have thread-local bindings, thus you can freely use `set!` on them:

```
(thread-bound? #'*unchecked-math*)
=> true
```

whereas `(def ^:dynamic *x*)` only creates a root binding:

```
(thread-bound? #'*x*)
=> false
```

The `binding` macro creates a new scope for a dynamic Var; on the low level, it temprorarily ['pushes'](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1902) bound values of given Vars to the current thread, and then ['pops'](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1920) them upon exiting the body of the macro.

```
(binding [*x* 1]
  (thread-bound? #'*x*))
=> true

(binding [*x* 1]
  (set! *x* 2))
=> 2
```